# Problems when converting KML files to GPX

Tags: qgis, gps, kml, gpx

Looking at the KML and the GPX file that I created (in QGIS through 'Save as'), in QGIS it looks as if the lines are all right (picture 1), but when I open it in another type of GPS program like bikegpx.com, the lines are all weird..

[image: The GPX file in QGIS]
[image: The GPX file in bikegpx.com]

Can anyone tell me, how to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you sure this is wrong? It just looks like all the individual segments are automatically connected in the second picture, while not in the first one.

Comment: Mm, yeah I see what you mean.. but it's also missing the rest of the country.

Comment: My guess would be the app just can't handle disjoint tracks. Or several in one file.

Comment: Huh, that sure would be nice - and save me a lot of trouble. Thanks, for the comments.